# Does every shrine in Tears of the Kingdom have a treasure chest?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Do all of the shrines in The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom have at least one treasure chest?

Comment: Not sure, but in BotW, I believe all had two (other than feats of strength), one relatively easy to get, the other needs work. I've come across many so far that seemed to only have one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Tears of the Kingdom, like its predecessor, will show a treasure chest icon **next to the shrine’s name** on the map. The visibility of this icon indicates whether you’ve gotten all of the chests in the shrine, which implies that every shrine will have at least one chest. The map icon actively updates, so you can check before you complete/leave a shrine.

[image: Example of Shrines on the map. Top portion of the image shows a shrine where all chests were not found, while the bottom portion a shrine with a chest icon indicating that all chests were found.]

<sup>Top is an example of a shrine where all chests were ***not*** found. Bottom, with the chest icon, shows all chests were found. Screenshots are from BotW, but it looks exactly the same in TotK.</sup>

Comment: Just commenting to emphasize that the chest icon appears next to the ***shrine's name, not the shrine's symbol***. I had read *shrine's symbol* (although that's not what it's written) and for the life of me I couldn't see it. I've had to google it and that's when I've seen that's next to the name!

Comment: Got that all in bold now for the future @xtropic type of ppl ;)

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me: Does the icon being visible mean that I have found the chests? Or does it appear if there are unopened chests? If there are multiple chests, are there multiple icons, one for each chest?

Comment: @Madjura I find it a bit unintuitive myself, but the chest icon indicates that **you have found all the chests**.

Comment: @Madjura I’ve added a bit more description of what the screenshot is depicting to try to clear that up. Let me know if you think the answer can still use more clarity.

Comment: If I find a chest, but due to my inventory being full choose to leave the weapon behind in it, will the icon update?

Comment: @Show in BotW, if the chest is closed, you don’t get the icon. Doesn’t matter that you tried to open it and failed because of inventory limits. I haven’t tested, but I’d expect TotK to behave the same way.

Comment: @BambooleanLogic It does **not** indicate merely finding all the chests. It indicates getting the items out of the chests. If you find a chest and leave its contents there due to a full inventory, it **does not** show the icon.