# What do the checkmarks on caves mean?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I've noticed that some cave icons on my map have checkmarks next to them while others don't. What does the checkmark symbol mean?

[image: Caves with checkmarks]

Comment: No, for those wondering, it does not mean the caves are paying $8/mo to be "verified" :P

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a similar vein as the [treasure chest icon on shrines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/402762/222207), a checkmark will appear on the cave if you've found the cave's Bubbulfrog and recovered its Bubbul Gem:

[image: Bubbulfrog]

From [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom/Bubbul_Gems_-_Rewards_and_Tips):

> Once you’ve entered a cave and collected the Bubbul Gem, that cave will get a Check Mark on your map, so you know you don’t have to revisit it.

Like in the case of shrine chests, this implies that every cave will contain a Bubbulfrog. Keep an eye on the ceilings until you find it!

Comment: The caves on the starting Great Sky Island are an exception. They don't contain Bubbulfrogs, but all of them have a checkmark on my map.

Comment: @Stevoisiak I wonder if that's Great Sky Island-specific or if it's because Bubbulfrogs only live on the surface, so NO sky island caves will have them (I personally haven't encountered caves anywhere but Great Sky Island to confirm or deny this difference)

Comment: My SO is adamant it also is that you have found the chest within. Any source that could prove/disprove that?

Comment: @Fredy31 I've added a quote from IGN to the answer. It should be pretty simple to test though. Find a new cave, *DON'T* open any chests, kill the Bubbulfrog, check your map. (I can tell you anecdotally that that's all it'll take to get the check--no chest involved)

Comment: Beyond the implication from IGN, there is a [loading screen hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek7Tr.jpg) that confirms there is indeed a Bubbulfrog in each cave.