# Where is the Bubbulfrog for the Hebra Great Skeleton?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

On the map for TOTK, caves will [show a checkmark](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/402796/181240) when you've defeated the Bubbulfrog inside and obtained its Bubbul Gem.

Where is the Bubbulfrog for the Hebra Great Skeleton?

[image: Map with Hebra Great Skeleton]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the IGN guide for Hebra Mountains](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom/Hebra_Mountains):

> Hebra Great Skeleton - (-3823, 3602, 0257); Bubblefrog is actually close to the entrance on the other side of a huge piece of stalactite.

You can see it at the top of this image.

[image]

<sup>Its not listed in [Game8's full list of caves and Bubbulfrogs](https://game8.co/games/Zelda-Tears-of-the-Kingdom/archives/411749), but I'm guessing that's because it's an incomplete list (there are several other caves missing Bubbulfrog locations as well).</sup>